# <%= %> Expression not evaluated when coming from a Dynamic content

Tags: web8.5, cil

I am using [CILs](https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/b/blog-posts/posts/getting-started-with-content-interaction-library-cil-in-web-8-it-39-s-really-quite-simple) in my application to fetch data from the Contnet Broker databae  using Discovery Servies.
The application works fine for fetching contents from normal dynamic Component Presentation. But when the CP contains the a any c# expression Tags like `<%= , <%@` etc. , the application treates those as normal string and does not evaluate those.

Check the attached screenshot.

[image]

Am I missing any reference to make it work.

Please help.

** I am using Web 8.5 version.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behavior when retrieving items from a data source. The application server is only able to execute expressions when they are on a file system as aspx pages or controls or custom loaded into memory.

Here is a blog post that covers this topic for a java-based architecture. However, the same concepts would apply for a .NET architecture. http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/12/executing-jsp-dcp-stored-in-database.html

The topic of executing expressions from a database has been discussed by a number of threads out there on the internet. If you google ".net execute expression from database" you'll get a nice list. Here are a few examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically

http://www.codemag.com/article/0211081